# Is it good industry practice to use whenComplete to mark completion of CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, completable-future

Is it good industry practice to use `.whenComplete` to log errors and completion of completable future when the requirement is just to log the result and error if there is any?
See the template

```
void function() {
   CompletableFuture
     .runAsync(() -> runAsyncfunction())
     .whenComplete((result, err) -> {//log the error})
 }
```

If this is not the right way, then what is?
I m using Spring Boot application, if there is any functionality in spring boot to handle such things ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"to mark completion"*? If you just leave it alone, the future will complete and vanish into the void. If you need to take some action when `runAsyncfunction()` is done, then that's a different thing, and using `whenComplete` to perform that action is one of your options. This is not really a design of a process flow where you'd have "right" trigger and event types, it's just about knowing what CompletableFuture methods are designed for and using them for your requirement.

Comment: What if someone invokes `runAsyncfunction()` without being in a function within `runAsync`? Isn’t it the responsibility of `runAsyncfunction()` itself to catch and report errors? Otherwise, what’s the purpose of the background action that apparently nobody depends on, anyway?

Comment: @Holger I agree but isn't ```whenComplete``` is one generic solution to catch all the errors and log the error thrown by ```runAsyncFunction()```  for the developers to know that the background didn't run as expected. 
NOTE : here I m talking about errors which are not caught in ```runAsyncFunction()``` itself, ofcourse the function itself should handle the errors which we know can occur.

Comment: You can use `whenComplete` for that purpose and there’s nothing wrong with that. But there is no industry requirement to do so. Like all of these methods, `runAsync` returns a `CompletableFuture` that can be queried for its completion state, so if there is already a receiving end, that might be the place to check for errors and handle them. To me, it looks unusual not to have someone being interested in that object. But it all depends on the context…

Comment: @Holger Yes I got your point, thanks.